# How do I differentiate $K_\alpha$ from $L_\alpha$ transitions of X-ray emissions?

Tags: x-rays

If I shine an electron beam in a sample and it returns, for an example, an X-ray wavelength compatible with both $K_\alpha$ of copper and $L_\alpha$ of hafnium. How can I tell the difference between these elements?

Edit: Using Moseley Law [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkZ4o.jpg) I get copper for $K_\alpha$ and hafnium for $L_\alpha$ for an wavelength of 0.155 nm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, since $\rm K_{\alpha}$ for Copper is $8.046\,\rm MeV$ and $\rm L_{\alpha}$ for Europium is $5.849\,\rm MeV$.

The energies of the X-rays are well defined, as are the wavelengths of light in the visible part of em spectrum, so differentiation is not normally a problem.

With the error corrected by the author of the post from Europium to  Hafnium, $\rm L_{\alpha}$ is $7.899\,\rm MeV$ which is significantly different (ie relatively easily measurable) from the Copper.

It probably shows that the author of the OP was not working to sufficient significant figures?

Comment: Using the moseley law for frequencies of $L_\alpha$ and $K_\alpha$, for an wavelenght of 0.155 nm. It returns me both copper and europium. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/yhGzAxj)

Comment: sorry, just saw that i messed up. Its not europium, its hafnium.

Answer (score 1):

One looks at the spectrum. There should also be a weaker $\beta$ line at slightly higher energy (shorter wavelength). An L$_\beta$ line is almost as strong as the L$_\alpha$ but a K$_\beta$ would be four of five times weaker.